# HelmDeploy@0 Azure DevOps Task uninstall not working

Tags: azure-devops, kubernetes-helm, kubectl

I try to uninstall a helm chart with my azure devops pipeline with this task:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/helm-deploy-v0?view=azure-pipelines

Sadly it is not working as documented.

My error is:

```
##[error]Error: "helm uninstall" requires at least 1 argument
Usage:  helm uninstall RELEASE_NAME [...] [flags]
helm.go:84: [debug] "helm uninstall" requires at least 1 argument
```

My input is:

```
       - task: HelmDeploy@0
         displayName: Helm Chart deinstallieren, wenn vorhanden
          inputs:
        connectionType: Azure Resource Manager
        azureSubscriptionEndpoint: Azure Resource Manager
        azureResourceGroup: MyRG
        kubernetesCluster: MyAKS
        command: uninstall
```

So what i tried allready is using CharType and ChartName and ReleaseName - but still the same.

Installation is working fine with:

```
        - task: HelmDeploy@0
      displayName: Helm Chart installieren
      inputs:
        connectionType: Azure Resource Manager
        azureSubscriptionEndpoint: Azure Resource Manager
        azureResourceGroup: MyRG
        kubernetesCluster: MyAKS
        command: install
        chartType: FilePath
        chartPath: infrastructure/helm/${{parameters.chart}}/${{parameters.version}}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I was looking at the source code for the task and I think this might be a bug with the task. Have you tried enable diagnostic logging to see what the exact `helm` command looks like?

Comment: yes I have but there is nothing I could see, else then that the RELEASE_NAME will be needed when using helm uninstall - and is problably not used even the parameter is set...

Answer (score 2):

Can you try to add the following to your task inputs like so:

```
inputs: 
  arguments: > 
    "your release name"
```

Answer (score 0):

Helm uninstall command is as below

```
helm uninstall {deployment name} -n {namespace}
```

Hence HelmDeploy@0 trying to execute this command .

Error is saying usage of command is as

```
Usage:  helm uninstall RELEASE_NAME [...] [flags]
```

It means it is expecting release name or deployment name

So your task should be as below

```
- task: HelmDeploy@0
  displayName: Helm Chart installieren
  inputs:
    connectionType: Azure Resource Manager
    azureSubscriptionEndpoint: Azure Resource Manager
    azureResourceGroup: MyRG
    releaseName: MyReleaseName
    kubernetesCluster: MyAKS
    command: install
    chartType: FilePath
    chartPath: infrastructure/helm/${{parameters.chart}}/${{parameters.version}}
    arguments: >
        MyReleaseName
```

If you want to parameterized release name you can use as below

```
- task: HelmDeploy@0
  displayName: Helm Chart installieren
  inputs:
    connectionType: Azure Resource Manager
    azureSubscriptionEndpoint: Azure Resource Manager
    azureResourceGroup: MyRG
    releaseName: $(ReleaseName)
    kubernetesCluster: MyAKS
    command: install
    chartType: FilePath
    chartPath: infrastructure/helm/${{parameters.chart}}/${{parameters.version}}
    arguments: >
        $(ReleaseName)
```